# Twilio try to send sms from dashboard to emirates number

Tags: twilio, sms, verification

i cannot send any sms from Twilio to and number on United Arab Emirates , always face below  error :
"Test SMS failed. 21612. Message cannot be sent with the current combination of "To" and/or "From" parameters.  Learn more"

"Test SMS failed. 21612. Message cannot be sent with the current combination of "To" and/or "From" parameters.  Learn more"

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you cannot use this number to send messages to this country. Maybe you can try to purchase a Twilio number from another country and use that one?

From the [docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181868-Troubleshooting-Undelivered-Twilio-SMS-Messages#:%7E:text=Error%2021610%3A%20You%20are%20attempting,is%20not%20a%20supported%20carrier):

> Error 21610: You are attempting to send a message to a number that has opted out of receiving messages using a STOP keyword.
>
> Error 21612. This error can have two explanations:
>
> The carrier you are sending to is not a supported carrier. Twilio supports most carriers worldwide, but there are still carriers which we do not yet support. To determine if Twilio supports a particular carrier, please search for the country on the SMS Pricing page and scroll to the section labeled "All SMS Pricing for..." If the carrier does not appear on that list, Twilio cannot send SMS messages to that carrier at this time.
> The "To" phone number is not properly formatted. We suggest all "To" numbers should use E.164 formatting to help ensure proper routing.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 I had this issue with trying to receive an OTP from Instarem. Eventually Instarem said: "Our tech team checked with Twilio and UAE number is not registered for alphanumeric SID required for local regulator carrier and hence unable to receive the otp"

There is only one telecom provider (the gov) owning the network really in UAE which is Du (and Etisalat/E&). I think Porkbun must use Twilio as they are having issues sending me an OTP today and I had similar problems with Kixify app in 2023. The UK government can send them here no issue so just Twilio's problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is required by law to register with [TRA](https://tdra.gov.ae/en/) in order to send SMS to customers, this can be done with any provider like Twilio, Vonage or else.